# SQL IN clause - NEST C# - ElasticSearch Terms not working with anothers filters

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST 6.0.1 with same elasticsearch version.
I'm trying to make a select using .Terms. Alone, it works ok, but together with others filters like .Must... seems the .Terms is ignoring the .Must filters.

```
// Params comming in request method:
ElasticClient client, int maximumRows, string jobId, string merchantId, string category, ICollection<int> priorityFilterCollection

var searchResponse = client.Search<LogEntity>(s => s
                                        .From(0)
                                        .Size(maximumRows)
                                        .Query(q => q
                                            .Bool(b => b
                                                .Must(
                                                    sd => sd.MatchPhrase(m => m
                                                        .Field(f => f.JobId)
                                                        .Query(jobId)
                                                        )
                                                )
                                                .Must(
                                                    sd => sd.MatchPhrase(m => m
                                                        .Field(f => f.MerchantId)
                                                        .Query(merchantId)
                                                        )
                                                )
                                                .Must(
                                                    sd => sd.MatchPhrase(m => m
                                                        .Field(f => f.Category)
                                                        .Query(category)
                                                        )
                                                )
                                                .Must(
                                                    sd => sd.Terms(m => m
                                                        .Field(f => f.Priority)
                                                        .Terms<int>(priorityFilterCollection)
                                                        )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    );
```

Answer (score 1):

A call to `Must` on the bool query descriptor is assignative, so with multiple calls, only the last one is assigned to the must clause. The bool query needs to be rewritten in order to pass multiple must clauses

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<LogEntity>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(maximumRows)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(
                sd => sd.MatchPhrase(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.JobId)
                    .Query(jobId)
                    ),
                sd => sd.MatchPhrase(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.MerchantId)
                    .Query(merchantId)
                    ),
                sd => sd.MatchPhrase(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Category)
                    .Query(category)
                    ),
                sd => sd.Terms(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Priority)
                    .Terms<int>(priorityFilterCollection)
                    )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Check out the [Writing bool queries documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response! 

I'm new to elasticsearch, so I have a lot of questions.
One question... 

You're saying that with multiples .Must, the code always will consider the last .Must, right?

Why if I take out the last ".Must" with ".Terms<int>(p...",  all the others filters continue working? The problem was only with the last .Must that was contending the ".Terms<int>(p...".

My solution (that worked for me) to put the ".Filter(..." after last .Must, is it wrong?

Comment: `.Must(...)` **must** be called once, and passed a `params Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer>[] queries`. See the method signature: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/13aed8a519565a1b3f49ee944e78372fd953924e/src/Nest/QueryDsl/Compound/Bool/BoolQuery.cs#L180-L184. With the query in the question, only the `terms` query in the last `Must` clause would have been serialized and sent in the search request. _Why_ that `terms` query does not yield the results expected is another question, but it's unrelated to the query structure :)

Comment: I really have to recognize that you are right. I did some others tests and using various .Must() .Must()... the filter not work very well. Thanks for your response!